# Chromium is really slow in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, internet, chromium

I just installed Xubuntu 12.04.3 on my Toshiba Satellite, and I've noticed that Chromium is REALLY slow.  I have a 3 bar WiFi signal, so it can't be that.  Also, when the computer ran Windows, it actually got faster internet.  Is there a way to get faster internet?

Answer (score 0):

When you say your internet is slow, are you refering to the actual speed you're obtaining from your isp or it just appears to be running slowly? If you run a speedtest from speedtest.net and compare it to what you're paying for from your ISP and it is a major difference, I'd check that your network adapter's are up to date driver-wise.

If Chromium is the only browser running slow I would suggest uninstalling it and trying a fresh install.